# PCB vs SMD antenna for 2G cellular IoT device

Tags: pcb, antenna, pcb-antenna, cellular

I am designing an IoT module to read water sensors in an Agricultural field, then send the data through cellular to the cloud. My design uses the SIM800H, a quad band cellular modem, to send and receive signal.

I need to decide what kind of cellular antenna to use: SMD or pre-made PCB. I found a few options [here](http://www.taoglas.com/product-category/2g-3g-antennas/internal-gsm-cdma/), but no general guidance on how to choose one. Note I am not going to build my own antenna in the PCB, but instead will buy a pre-made PCB antenna. The SMD antennas are smaller and easier to mount (just soldered with the other parts), but will they have the same range as the PCB antennas? What are the pros and cons of each type?

Comment: If you don't know how to read antennae specs, and how ground plane, cover dielectric, and tree leaves affect signal level or do Friis Path Loss, you have much to learn.

Comment: Use a pre-certified mobile module. Telit is one company that sells them. There are others, too. This will make your life easier in many ways. Probably an external antenna will have more range.

Comment: I thought the SIM800 was pre-certified?

Comment: Somehow I missed that you were using a SIM800. Maybe it is pre-certified. But if so, then I guess it has no onboard antenna. It must have a connector for an antenna. I think the antenna selection will affect certification. Antenna datasheets should have radiation patterns that will help you decide which one will give best results. If the antenna is stationary, you may benefit from using a directional antenna aimed at the nearest cell tower.